# Sizing nodes in GraphDB Visual Graph based on the number of edges

Tags: graphdb

I am trying to shape the graph I am working on with respect to the nodes(bubbles) sizes. Is there a way to size bubbles based on the edges they have on the particular graph? Would it be possible not to change the size of the bubble if after the expansion (<->) the number of the connected nodes (unrelated to the given graph) increases?
I am using GraphDB Enterprise Workbench.
Thank you in advance!

I was trying to find sample on the Internet and advised solutions from Bard (Google AI). Did not work out, unfortunately.